# cx_freeze error with pyodbc

Tags: pyodbc, cx-freeze

if you have a simple program name pyodbcTest.py

```
import pyodbc
print "pass"
```

and then use cx_freeze to compile it

```
cxfreeze --targe-dir=cxTest pyodbcTest.py
```

and then run that program it throws the following error.

```
C:\temp\pythonWork\cxTest>pyodbcTest.exe                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                               
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>     
        exec code in m.__dict__                                                                     
    File "pyodbcTest.py", line 1, in <module>                                           
 RuntimeError: Unable to import decimal
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add the option --include-module decimal to solve the problem.  Not sure why it could not find that one on its own during the freeze process, but its working now

Comment: Can you say exactly where you added "--include-module decimal" ? Was it to the command line when building or was it inside of the build script? Can you copy / paste exactly what you put? Thanks!

Comment: @advocate This response is a little bit late, but in case somebody else stumbles upon this question, adding something like `options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["pyodbc", "decimal"]}}` to `setup()` in my setup.py file worked for me.